# If statement ignores number value

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Apologies for being so inept!

```
let country = "UK";
let language = "English";
let population = 60;
let isIsland = false;

if (language === "English", population < 50, isIsland === false) {
console.log(`You should live in ${country} :)`);
} else {
console.log(`${country} does not meet your criteria`);
}
```

Here whatever i make the variable of population to be it seems to be ignored by the If statement and im not sure why!

Comment: You should use the [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) (`&&`) instead of the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

Comment: use ```&&``` instead comma between conditions  ```if (language === "English" && population < 50 && isIsland === false)```

Comment: Right, that's not how JavaScript works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing logical operator in if statement. Logical operators are use to test for true or false. There are three logical operators in JavaScript.

- And(&&)
- or(||)
- not(!)

```js
let country = "UK";
let language = "English";
let population = 60;
let isIsland = false;

if (language === "English" && population < 50 && isIsland === false) {
  console.log(`You should live in ${country} :)`);
} else {
  console.log(`${country} does not meet your criteria`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"or" condition:

```
if (language === "English" || population < 50 || isIsland === false)
```

"and" condition

```
if (language === "English" && population < 50 && isIsland === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use and (&&) operator for that

```
if (language === "English" && population < 50 && isIsland === false) {
console.log(`You should live in ${country} :)`);
} else {
console.log(`${country} does not meet your criteria`);
}
```